# Do any languages use suffixes to represent place value in numbers?

Tags: numbers

As part of a book I'm writing, I'm making a language that uses suffixes on number words to represent place values. English uses "-ty" for this purpose to mark tens, but I want to do it to larger place values like hundred or million.

Are there any word-based languages that use suffixes rather than entire words to mark higher place values, so that I can study their numbering systems to come up with better suffixes?

Answer (score 1):

The trouble with your question is that it is not clear what "word" and "suffix" mean cross-linguistically; but I think Japanese meets your criterion.

The "power-of-ten" suffixes like *-hyaku* (hundred) *-sen* (thousand) *-man* (ten thousand) are a special case of so-called classifiers, such as *-nen* (counting people) and *-mai* (counting flat things), and are combined with the number word into, probably, a single word, as can be seen by certain sandhi rules; so

> nihyaku = 200
>
> nisen = 2,000
>
> niman = 20 000

but

> ippyaku (< ichi-hyaku) = 100
>
> issen (< ichi-sen) = 1,000
>
> ichiman = 10,000

I believe that this system is imported wholesale from Chinese, but I know much less about that, which is why I have concentrated on Japanese.

Comment: I actually wanted to comment on that in the original question - I know that Chinese and Japanese have a suffix-like system of affixing another character after the number, but I was looking for examples in languages whose morphology treats the suffixes as lower-class citizens than Chinese tends to do. So basically, specifically excluding languages whose number system is derived from Chinese.

Comment: Especially in Japanese, the words can usually be used by themselves without problem; you'd usually use hyaku (百) by itself, not ippyaku (一百).

Comment: I don't speak Japanese, but I think the Chinese system uses compounding rather than affixation.

Comment: Joe Z. is correct: _hyaku_ amd _sen_ are not suffixes, while _-man_ is. You can say _hyaku-en_ (100 Yen) or _sen-en_ (1000 Yen), but not _man-en_. In that sense, Colin Fine's answer is incorrect, because the question is about suffixes. I agree, however, that the question should be changed to whether there are languages that use "affixes". Also note that Japanese also uses the suffixes _-oku_ (10<sup>8</sup>) and _-tyoo_ (10<sup>12</sup>).

Answer (score 1):

English -ty stems from an actual, albeit contracted, noun, though (from *tigiwiz*, plural of *tegun* "ten"). If we still want to regard -ty as a suffix, then Russian has something similar: *pyatsot, shestsot, semsot, vosemsot, deviatsot* (500, 600, 700, 800). Although, technically the latter part is still very noun-like (stems from the noun meaning "hundred"), as seen in its declension (NOM trista > INSTR tremiastami); however it's regarded as one word by Russian grammarians, it's spelled as one word, and I think most people perceive it as one single word (I guess it's viewed as one single word because you can't put random words between the parts).

Comment: I'd say there's a simpler reason for their being seen as one word: having only one stressed syllable.

Comment: In oblique cases like *dvumiastami*, there are two stressed syllables, though.

Comment: I'm not sure there are. I've asked this on Russian SE: http://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/9317/do-instrumental-forms-of-numerals-like-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-have-secondary-stress

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to post comments there. I think a potential problem with двумястами is that it's more of an educated form, as in colloquial speech compound numerals tend to be indeclinable. Also I see you cited the Russian wiktionary; the English wiktionary on the other hand has двумя́ста́ми :)